# How to set the back ground image to a button in swift (When button is clicked)

Tags: swift, uibutton, background-image

I wrote the code like this but its not working properly.

```
func refreshPageData() {
        if(isAudioSelected)
        {
            self.songsButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"rectangle54")!)
            self.songsButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
            self.videosButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
```

Comment: `isAudioSelected` is `true`?

Comment: **isAudioSelected** is set to true when the button is clicked?

Comment: yes audio selected true

Comment: Can you tell us when you are calling `refreshPageData` method?

Comment: Like -       self.songsButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"rectangle54")!, for: .normal)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func refreshPageData() {
   if(isAudioSelected)
   {
      self.songsButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"rectangle54")!, for: .normal)
      self.songsButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
      self.videosButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
   }
}
```